# Do I need to use a class to use its methods in my subclass in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

Alrighty, coding in Perl and just had a quick question. I have class created called SubtitleSite which is basically an abstraction, and a class called podnapisi that inherits SubtitleSite like this:

```
@ISA = qw(SubtitleSite);
```

My question is, do I have to use:

```
use SubtitleSite;
```

in order to have access to all the methods in SubtitleSite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but most of the time you're better off not messing with `@ISA` directly.  Just `use parent qw(SubtitlesSite);`, it will load `SubtilteSite` for you and add it to `@ISA`.

Comment: Note that `parent` did not become a core module until 5.10. If you're using an older perl you'll either need to use the older `base` pragma or install `parent`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Some more info can be found here:

- http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perloop.htm#PerlInheritance

Answer (score 2):

YES.

Otherwise the symbols defined in SubtitleSite are undefined in podnapisi.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the methods, you'd either have to inherit from it, or delegate to an object of it's type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are constructing an object in your child class, you can just call methods on yourself and they will be found through the magic of inheritance (see [perldoc perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation) for more about `SUPER`):

```
sub foo
{
    my $this = shift;
    $this->method_on_parent;  # this works!
    $this->SUPER::foo;        # this works too
}
```

However if these classes are only library functions that don't use OO, you have to tell Perl explicitly where to find the function:

```
ParentClass::function;    # use the class name explicitly
```